# Is there a way to enumerate active buffs/debuffs on a character?

Tags: dont-starve, reign-of-giants, dont-starve-shipwrecked

In *Don't Starve* (and DLCs), various status effects influence the rise and fall of health, hunger and sanity over time:

- Proximity to monsters/friends
- Items worn or in inventory
- Things eaten
- Time of day
- Wetness
- Temperature
- Poison

In addition to these, there are several "one-time" ways to gain health, hunger or sanity, such as eating foods (adds or subtracts any of the three), being attacked (damages health), sleeping in a tent (adds sanity but lowers hunger), etc. -- but I am not interested in instantaneous buffs/debuffs.

I occasionally see my sanity (in particular) draining when I don't think it should be. I'd like to be able to know which status effects are active on my character at a given time. I imagine this could be done via the [console](http://dontstarve.wikia.com/wiki/Console) while the game is paused, but I don't see any documentation describing how this could be done. (For me, I'd prefer not to use a mod that takes up screen space when I'm not interested in seeing all active effects -- I only want to see the effects at certain times.)

**Is there a way to enumerate the active status effects on a character?**

Comment: How would you want this information displayed? Considering how many things can affect one or more stats, your HUD would be awash in numbers. And as you noted, it's not just _things_ but time of day and season. There are influences coming from all over.